# mysqldump fails with "Skipping dump data for table 'table1', it has no fields"

Tags: mysql

I'm running mysqldump from an older mysql database. The mysqldump is part of a mariadb distribution if it matters.

When I run mysqldump locally, it's fine. When I run it on a remote system, I get no data dumped. If I run it with `mysqldump -v` the last line is

```
Skipping dump data for table 'table1', it has no fields
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From some googling and this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/7ehzzp/is_mysqldump_broken_in_stretch/), I determined that you need to set the default locale.

So the command that worked for me was:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 --lock-tables=false --single-transaction=TRUE --host=$HOST --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD $DB
```

I used both lock-tables and single transaction because I have a mix of myisam and innodb tables.